# How to grouping and summing Jarrays based on certain keys

Tags: c#, arrays

i have data and code like this for filtering by country and count it.
but i can only filter them one by one.

Data :

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Amal",
      "Country":"India",
      "salary":"4.000,00"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Luke",
      "Country":"England",
      "salary":"2.500,00"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Tom",
      "Country":"Australia",
      "salary":"2.700,00"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Ram",
      "Country":"India",
      "salary":"2.000,00"
   }
]
```

Code :

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
   
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                string inputJson = "[{'Name':'Amal', 'Country':'India','salary':'4.000,00'},{'Name':'Luke', 'Country':'England','salary':'2.500,00'},{'Name':'Tom', 'Country':'Australia','salary':'2.700,00'}, {'Name':'Ram', 'Country':'India','salary':'2.000,00'}]";
                var jArrObject = JArray.Parse(inputJson);
                Console.WriteLine("***Employee Data***");
                var employee = new JArray(jArrObject.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.Country=='India')]"));
                Console.WriteLine("Total Employee : "+employee.Count);
                Console.WriteLine("Employee : "+employee);
            }
        }
```

I was expecting to get a result like this :

```
[
   {
      "country":"India",
      "Total Employee":"2",
      "Total Salary":"6.000,00"
   },
   {
      "country":"England",
      "Total Employee":"1",
      "Total Salary":"2.500,00"
   },
   {
      "country":"Australia",
      "Total Employee":"1",
      "Total Salary":"2.700,00"
   }
]
```

how to make an array object group by country and add sum salaries according to the country?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to project the data into an anonymous type (or create a static type to use). Then you can serialize the result or do whatever you want:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-gb");
ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator= ",";
ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator =".";

var result = jArrObject.GroupBy(ao => ao["Country"])
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Country = a.Key,
        TotalEmployee = a.Count(),
        TotalSalary = a.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x["salary"].ToString(),NumberStyles.Number, ci ))
    });
```